# Syntax question: return catch-all value in match{}

Tags: rust, syntax

A simple syntax question, but can't google it.

For example, i want to write a function that returns a value of `i`, but if `i == 5`, it should return 0 instead. Can I write it as a single `match`?

```
fn get_i(i: i32) -> i32 {
    match i {
        5 => 0,
        _ => ???,
    }
}
```

Comment: you mean `if i == 5 { 0 }  else { i }` ?

Comment: What do you mean by a "single match"? Why can't you use `i` for the `???`? Why use a match for a single condition instead of an `if`?

Comment: Yes, i mean if i == 5 { 0 }  else { i }, but with a match. Obviously, it is a simplified example.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the issue. Replace the `???` with `i` and you're done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For your *particular* example there is indeed a simpler solution, as pointed out in the comments:

```rust
fn get_i(i: 32) -> i32 {
  if i == 5 {
    0
  } else {
    i
  }
}
```

But let's say you have a more complex pattern and I guess your question is how you'd return the catch-all value in that case.

Well, there's nothing special, in terms of patterns, about `_`. You can use any other symbol, too. So you can just write

```rust
fn get_i(n: i32) -> i32 {
    match n {
        5 => 0,
        i => i,
    }
}
```

This works because if your pattern on the lefthand side is just a single name, it will match *anything* and bind it to that name.

You can use anything for the lefthand side that's a valid variable name, and then use that in the righthand side of your pattern.

The same happens when you use `_`, just with the understanding and convention that Rust won't warn you when a variable that begins with `_` isn't actually used. That's why you see `_` often used for the catch-all pattern when it's just meant to return some default that's unrelated to the actual input, but there's no reason you can't use another variable name.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I needed. The `_ => _` makes errors, but with a literal name it works.

Comment: @BarafuAlbino Not sure what you mean by `return _`, there's [no return involved](https://gist.github.com/davelnewton/02fbb79b2a0bdb5e11bbeb9e76f7c89e).

Comment: `_ => _` doesn't really make any sense, though; you know what value you want to return on the match: `i`.